# as.POSIXct returning a double when used in a function instead of DateTime

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a messy database to deal with where the date time was sometimes stored as 24 hour format with no seconds and other times it was stored as 12 hour time format with AM/PM at the end (could have happened during a Windows update of our measurement computer or something, I don't know).

I want to convert the DateTime string to a usable DateTime object with as.POSIXct but when I try the follow code it is converted into a double (checked the class it is also numeric)

```
main_function <- function(res_df)
{
 res_df <- res_df %>%
    mutate(DateTime = sapply(DateTime, date_time_convert))
}


date_time_convert <- function(dt_string, tz="Europe/Amsterdam")
{
  if(str_detect(dt_string, "M")){
    dt_format <- "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
  }else
  {
    dt_format <- "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
  }
  
 as.POSIXct(dt_string, format=dt_format, tz=tz)
}
```

When I debug, the code executes properly in the function (returns a DateTime object), but when it moves into my dataframe the dates are all converted into doubles.

Comment: Use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as `sapply` converts to `matrix` and this results in coersion to its stored data type

Comment: Also, you may use `parse_date` from `parsedate` which could automatically pick up the formats and  then you can use without any loops i.e. `res_df %>% mutate(DateTime = parse_date(DateTime))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sapply` and similar do not always play well with `POSIXt` as an output. Here's an alternative: use `do.call(c, lapply(..., date_time_convert))`.

Demo with sample data:

```r
vec <- c("2021-01-01", "2022-01-01")

### neither 'sapply(..)' nor 'unlist(lapply(..))' work
sapply(vec, as.POSIXct)
# 2021-01-01 2022-01-01 
# 1609477200 1641013200 
unlist(lapply(vec, as.POSIXct))
# [1] 1609477200 1641013200

do.call(c, lapply(vec, as.POSIXct))
# [1] "2021-01-01 EST" "2022-01-01 EST"
```

which means your code would be

```r
res_df %>%
  mutate(DateTime = do.call(c, lapply(DateTime, date_time_convert)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Kind of inelegant, but if it works it works. Do you have any explanation of why this works the way it does?

Comment: The use of `do.call(c, ...)` works because it's really calling `do.call(c.POSIXct, ...)`, which concatenates the timestamps correctly. Internally what we'd need (if `L <- lapply(..)`) something like `c.POSIXct(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]], ...)`, but since we cannot know a priori the length of `L`, the use of `c.POSIXct` in the traditional way is impractical. Ergo the need for `do.call` which applies the unknown (to us) length results from `lapply` to `c.POSIXct`.

Comment: As to why `sapply` and `unlist` are broken in this regard, I have no idea why they did not safeguard `POSIXt`-class objects. There are other examples in R where base R functions break base R objects (try `ifelse` with `POSIXt` or `Date`, for example), but it's likely very difficult to do it all "perfectly" with a programming language that has grown over *decades* of use and adaptation.